# Help finding a math tutoring webinar

Tags: education

So, in addition to teaching I do some college math tutoring on the side, and my employer wants me to find and watch an online seminar of roughly one hour in length as part of my "professional development." The problem is, I am at a loss for where to look.

Any ideas? I would much appreciate suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really within the scope of this stack exchange community, but I will point you to the MIT Electronic Seminar on Math Education: https://math.mit.edu/seminars/emes/. (Did you mean seminars on teaching math, or seminars on math?)

Comment: That looks great, thank you!